# Why are parts of my teeth super white, but most yellow?

Tags: dentistry

I've noticed that teeth have white spots on them. What are they, why are they there and how can I remove them?

Comment: I've edited your question heavily because the answer is very different to what you think it is.  It would be relevant to know since when the white spots are there. Since childhood?